# What is Apex Code? Is it related to Java?

Tags: java, salesforce, force.com

I have being called for an training program for application development for Force.com. Since I am looking forward to work in a java based development environment, will it help me as a java developer in the future?

Comment: If you want to work on Force.com projects, it's useful. Otherwise I don't think it's worth the time/money. Apex code is different from Java, and learning it now could confuse you. On the other hand, you could learn from good java frameworks what Apex *might* teach you. So my advice is, if you want to work with java, do work with it.

Comment: if its gonna give me some knowledge on java frameworks, i'm definitely going to do it. Thanks a lot for your feedback.

Comment: I meant "if you want to work with java, do work with Java". But anyways...

Comment: Considering the comments of two of you gentlemen, I denied the offer. Anyway, I wanted to thank you again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apex itself is based on Java, however syntax and some classes aside the style of programming is quite different in nature as it's more like web development than standalone application development.

Furthermore, even though Eclipse is the SDK of choice, you don't really use it as anything more than a glorified text editor, and one where auto-complete etc. regularly fail at that. It will help you practice coding and experience is always one of the best teachers, but with regards to general application development the amount of help it will provide is limited.

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback... it helps me a lot to make my decision.

Comment: So then do most Apex programmers wind up using VS Code?

Comment: These days it's probably the most popular IDE in use for Salesforce development thanks to the DX plugins. I use it (along with the CLI) and frankly it's a far better offering than we had when I wrote this answer.